# Add data from DropdownList to table(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Companies table and Vacancies.

Company have some number of Vacancies

I have View like this
[image: View]

So I select company  and second dropdown list is updated depending on company.

Here is View code (DropdownList section )

```
 <div class="right-grid-in-grid" style="width:100%;">
                <div style="margin-left:20px;width:50%; ">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Company", ViewBag.Companies as SelectList, new { @class = "greeting" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VacancyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left:20px;width:100%">
                    <select name="id" id="vacancy" style="width:55%" class="greeting" data-url="@Url.Action("Vacancies","Questions")" />
                </div>
```

Here is code for AJAX request

```
 $(function () {
        $("#Company").change(function (e) {
            var $vacancy = $("#vacancy");
            var url = $vacancy.data("url") + '?companyId=' + $(this).val();
            $.getJSON(url, function (items) {
                $.each(items, function (a, b) {
                    $vacancy.append('<option value="' + b.Value + '">' + b.Text + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

And here is controller code

```
 public ActionResult WelcomeScreen()
    {
        // Формируем список команд для передачи в представление
        //SelectList teams = new SelectList(db.Vacancy, "VacancyId", "VacancyName");
        //ViewBag.Teams = teams;

        ViewBag.Companies = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyID", "CompanyName");
        return View();
    }


    //Заносим инфу о вакансии в таблицу
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult WelcomeScreen(Interview interview)
    {
        db.Interview.Add(interview);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Questions", new { id = interview.Interview_Id });
    }
```

My problem in this -  I need to get VacancyId from second dropdownlist and write it to table.

All other data is writing well.

Not writing only VacancyId

Here is code of table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Interviews] (
[Interview_Id] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Greeting]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Detail]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[VacancyId]    INT            NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Interview_Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Interviews_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([VacancyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Vacancies] ([VacancyId]) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Comment: As far as i understand, you need to fetch the selected value from the second DDL. That's simple. Just use document.getElementById('whateveryouhavegiven').value. Then include this in the AJAX call and handle in your backend code

Comment: Some like

`VacancyId: $('#vacancy').val(),` ?@It'satrap

Comment: I am not sure about the Jquery syntax. But yes that only

Comment: What is `VacancyId`? Your form does not create a form control for that property. All you have is a `<select>` with `name="id"`, not `VacancyId`. Stop creating your html manually and use the `HtmlHelper` methods to bind to your model. And refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for how to correctly implement cascading dropdownlists

Comment: First, `ValidationMessageFor` won't work with only just `select` tag - it should have DDL helper: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VacancyId, ViewBag.Vacancies as SelectList, new { @id = "vacancy", @data_url = Url.Action("Vacancies","Questions")})`, and in JS: `var vacancy = $("#vacancy").val();`. Also the company DDL should bound to model too: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Company, ViewBag.Companies as SelectList, new { @id = "Company", @class = "greeting" })`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for all. I solve my problem yesterday

Here is code how to implement this using AJAX, in this AJAX call we get values from fields and pass them to backend.

Here is AJAX code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#save').click(function () {
        save();
    });
});
    function save() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            dataType: 'Json',
            data: {
                Detail: $('#Detail').val(),
                Greeting: $('#Greeting').val(),
                id: $('#vacancy').val(),


            },
            url: '@Url.Action("WelcomeScreenPost", "Questions")',
            success: function (da) {
                if (da.Result === "Success") {

                    window.location.href = da.RedirectUrl;

                } else {

                    alert('Error' + da.Message);
                }
            },
            error: function (da) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

On backend we will write this in Controller action method.

```
 [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult WelcomeScreenPost(string Detail, string Greeting, int id)
    {
        Interview inter = new Interview
        {

            Greeting = Greeting,
            Detail = Detail,
            VacancyId = id,
        };
        db.Interview.Add(inter);
        db.SaveChanges();
        var urlBuilder = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
        var url = urlBuilder.Action("Index", "Questions", new { id = inter.Interview_Id });
        return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully", RedirectUrl = url });
    }
```

And all will  works well.

Comment: Where in your question did you state you wanted to use ajax? And using ajax when you want to redirect is just crazy. Buy youself a good book and learn the basics (and study the DotNetFiddle I gave you in the link above).